# await on navigation pushasync?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

In Xamarin forms, the navigation methods such as [PushAsync](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushAsync/p/Xamarin.Forms.Page/) is a async `Task` returning method, but it looks whether using `await` when calling it makes no difference, is that right? Should I awaits these calls?

Another question, the [navigation guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/modal/) says model pages are used for  navigating to pages that requires finish self-contained tasks before dismissing it, but it looks it makes no difference between pushasync and pushmodelasync except for model pages there is no navigation bar, users can still use os back button to go back just like pushasync, is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usual considerations with awating apply here. If you don't `await` PushAsync and then perform another actions in your code after that (or your framework performs another actions you might not be aware about) - those actions might be performed before PushAsync is finished (that is - before page is presented to user). Also, if there is some exception in PushAsync operation - you won't notice it if you don't await the call. In general, even if you don't do anything after PushAsync - it's better to await the call (as with most other async operations) unless you know why exactly you don't want to do that.

As for second question, your link provides the answer:

> On Android and Windows Phone, the user can always return to the
>   previous page by pressing the standard Back button on the device. If
>   the modal page requires the user to complete a self-contained task
>   before leaving the page, the application must disable the Back button.
>   This can be accomplished by overriding the Page.OnBackButtonPressed
>   method on the modal page. For more information see Chapter 24 of
>   Charles Petzold's Xamarin.Forms book.

Comment: I have an example with a for loop that after the await that are still executed even with the await and before it complete. I have this await  Navigation.PushAsync(mypage, true); and after I have a for loop. How to execute the for loop after the task complete?